# `tikzpicture` is not working parallel with `\begin{table}… \end{table}`

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, packages

I am using `tikz` to draw a `tikzpicture` and it works properly. However, if I try to insert a table using the syntax

```
\begin{table} ...\end{table}
```

I get the error

```
Too many }'s. \end{table}
\begin{document} ended by \end{table}. \end{table}
Extra \endgroup. \end{table}
```

My TeX document is

```
 \documentclass[oneside,12pt,a4paper]{book}
    \usepackage{UTMThesis}%------------------------------------------------------------------
    \usepackage{cite} % change  cite from [1,2,3] to [1-3] etc for number system
    \makeatletter                        % change from
    \renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{#1.}  % [1] to 1. etc 
    \makeatother                         %  in list of references
    %----------------------------------------------------------------
    \setlength{\voffset}{-2.11cm}
    \setlength{\hoffset}{-.4cm}  
    %---------------------------------------------------------
    \setlength{\textwidth}{14.5cm}
    \setlength{\textheight}{24.5cm}
    %-----------------------------------------------------------
    %\pagestyle{plain}
    %-------------------------------------------------------
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \lhead{}
    \chead{}
    \rhead{}
    \lfoot{}   
    \cfoot{\vspace{-.35cm}\thepage}  %  
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    %----------------own-----------
    \usepackage{relsize}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning,tikzmark}
    %-------------------------------------------------------


    \begin{document}


        \begingroup\larger[4]
        \[
        \tikzmarknode{n1}{\rho\frac{D\vec V}{Dt}}~=~\tikzmarknode{n2}{-\nabla p}
        + \tikzmarknode{n3}{\rho\vec g}+\tikzmarknode{n4}{\mu\nabla^2\vec V}\]
        \endgroup
        \noindent
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,shorten <=1mm,font=\footnotesize\sffamily]
        \begin{scope}[nodes={text width=6.5em,align=left},node distance=1ex]
        \node (e1) {\underline{Total derivative}};
        \node[right=of e1.north east,anchor=north west] (e2) {\underline{Pressure gradient}\\[1em]
            Fluid flows in the direction\dots};
        \node[right=of e2.north east,anchor=north west] (e3) {\underline{Body force term}\\[1em]
            External forces\dots};
        \node[right=of e3.north east,anchor=north west] (e4) {\underline{Diffusion term}\\[1em]
            For a Newtonian fluid it is equatl to \dots};
        \end{scope}     
        \node[below=0.5ex of e1.south] (eq){$=$};
        \node[below=0.5ex of eq] (tot) {$\rho\left[\frac{\partial \vec V}{\partial t}
            +\left(\vec V\cdot\vec\nabla\right)\vec V\right]$};
        \path (tot.south west) -- (tot.south east) coordinate[pos=0.25] (tot1)
        coordinate[pos=0.75] (tot2);
        \node[below left=2ex and 0ex of tot.south,text width=4em,align=left] (c1) 
        {Change of velosity};
        \node[below right=2ex and 0ex of tot.south,text width=4em,align=left] (c2) {Convective term};
        \draw[cyan,-stealth] (c1) -- (tot1);
        \draw[cyan,-stealth] (c2) -- (tot2);
        \begin{scope}[overlay]
        \foreach \X in {1,...,4}
        {\draw[cyan,-stealth] (e\X) -- (n\X);} 
        \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{table}
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{c c c} 
                \hline
                a&b&c\\
                d&e&f\\             
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
\end{table}

    \end{document}
```

and `UTMThesis.sty` is

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% The package UTMthesis.sty will produce the output    %
% of a thesis according to UTM Thesis Manual,          %     
% School of Graduate Studies, 2007.                    %
% Yusof Yaacob, Department of Mathematical Sciences,             %
% Faculty of Science,  Universiti Teknologi Malaysia   %
% 81310 Johor Bahru, Malaysia                          %
% e-mail: yusofby@utm.my                               %
% 24 December 2009                                     %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% LaTeX cod for chapter header
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{
  %\vspace*{20\p@}   %  \vspace*{15\p@}
  {\parindent \z@ 
      \centering  
    \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter

      \normalsize 
           \bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter 
       \par\nobreak
              \vskip 1.4\baselineskip 
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \normalsize     
         \bfseries #1\par\nobreak 
       \vskip 1.4\baselineskip %
  }}
\def\@schapter#1{\if@twocolumn
                   \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{#1}]%
                 \else
                   \@makeschapterhead{#1}
                   \@afterheading
                 \fi}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{
  %\vspace*{20\p@} % \vspace*{20\p@} %
  {\parindent \z@  
    \centering  
    \normalfont 
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \normalsize 
    \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
         \vskip 1.4\baselineskip  
  }}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{CHAPTER}
%------------------------------------------------------------
% Commands for layout
   %\setlength{\topmargin}{-1.2cm}
   %\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1.7cm}   %\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1.46cm} 
\setlength{\textwidth}{14.5cm}
   \setlength{\textheight}{24.5cm} %  \setlength{\textheight}{24.5cm}
   %\setlength{\headheight}{2mm}
    %\setlength{\headsep}{10.175mm}
%-------------------------------------------------------------
% Command for 1.5 spacing
   %\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{doublespace}
\setstretch{1.5}
%-------------------------------------------------------------
% Command for  indentation
   \setlength\parindent{.5in}
   \usepackage{indentfirst} %1st line indented after section...
%-------------------------------------------------------------
% Command for space between paragraph
  \makeatletter
    %\setlength{\parskip}{1.5\baselineskip \@plus 3ex
                %  \@minus 2.0ex}
    \setlength{\parskip}{2\baselineskip \@plus .01ex
                  \@minus .01ex}
   \makeatother
%-------------------------------------------------------------
% Commands for no hyphenation and right justified
    \hyphenpenalty=10000 \sloppy
    \raggedbottom
%-------------------------------------------------------------
% Command to get rid of default running head
   \pagestyle{myheadings}
%-------------------------------------------------------------
% Command for  page number 
%  \makeatletter
%    \renewcommand{\ps@plain}{%
%    \renewcommand{\@oddhead}{\hfill\textrm{\thepage}}
%    \renewcommand{\@evenhead}{\@oddhead}
%    \renewcommand{\@evenfoot}{}
%    \renewcommand{\@oddfoot}{}  }
%   \makeatother
%-----------------------------------------------------------------

 %For section font
 % \usepackage{sectsty} 
  %  \chapterfont{\centering\normalsize\uppercase}
  %  \sectionfont{\normalsize\uppercase}
   % \subsectionfont{\normalsize}
   % \subsubsectionfont{\itshape\normalsize}
%---------------------------------------------------------
%--------------------------------------------------------------
% Commands for REFERENCES name
\renewcommand{\bibname}{REFERENCES}
%--------------------------------------------------------------
% Commands to change vertical space in section and subsection
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection
  {section}%      % the name
  {1}             % the level
  {0cm}           % the indent
  {1.0cm}         % the beforeskip
  {0.01cm}    %{0.5cm}    % the afterskip
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries} } % the style
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection
  {subsection}%   % the name
  {2}             % the leve2
  {0cm}           % the indent
  {1.0cm}         % the beforeskip
  {0.01cm} %{0.5cm}        % the afterskip
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries} } % the style
\makeatother
%--------------------------------------------------------------
% Commands to change horizontal space in section and subsection
% for times romans
   \renewcommand{\thesection} % space between sect. etc.
     {\thechapter.\arabic{section}\hspace{.12in}}
    \renewcommand{\thesubsection} 
       {\thesection\hspace{-.3cm}.\arabic{subsection} \hspace{-.135cm}} 
%--------------------------------------------------------------
% Commands for  TocLoFT
  \usepackage{tocloft}
    %\cftsetrmarg{2.75cm} %    
     \cftsetrmarg{1.5cm} %  
       \cftsetpnumwidth{1.25cm} 
       %\cftsetpnumwidth{1.25cm}
    \renewcommand{\cftdot}{} % get rid of dots
%Table of Contents
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{}        % off tocname
\setlength{\cftchapindent}{.8cm}      % chapter indent
\setlength{\cftsecindent}{2.3cm}      % section indent
\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{3.25cm}  % subsection indent
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{1.45cm}  % chp number width
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%  \renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{\rule{1.75ex}{0ex}}
%   \renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{\rule{1.75ex}{0ex}}
%   \renewcommand{\cftsubsecafterpnum}{\rule{1.75ex}{0ex}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{\rule{0.75ex}{0ex}}
   \renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{\rule{0.75ex}{0ex}}
   \renewcommand{\cftsubsecafterpnum}{\rule{0.75ex}{0ex}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   \renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont}
%-------------------------------------------------------------  
%List of Table
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{2.5cm}  %\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{2.5cm}  
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{} % off lotname
%\setlength{\cfttabindent}{-.015cm}      % table indent %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setlength{\cfttabindent}{-.1cm}      % table indent %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
             \renewcommand{\cfttabafterpnum}{\rule{2ex}{0ex}}
\cftsetrmarg{3cm}
%------------------------------------------------------------
 %List of Figure
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{2.5cm}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{} % off lofname
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{-.1cm}      % figure indent %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   \renewcommand{\cftfigafterpnum}{\rule{2ex}{0ex}}
%-------------------------------------------------------------
%-------------------------------------------------------------
% Command for bold caption
\makeatletter
  \long\def\@makecaption#1#2{\vskip 10\p@   % caption parameter
       \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{{#1\,\,\,\,\,} #2} %%%%%
       \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize         % caption parameter
           {#1\,\,\,\,\,}  #2\par  % caption parameter
       \else                                   % caption parameter
           \hbox to\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}  % caption parameter
   \fi}                                            % caption parameter
\makeatother   
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{table}}

%--------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{paralist} %refine list item
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{latexsym,amsmath,amssymb} % math symbols
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{graphicx} % .eps graphic
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{lscape} % for landscape
%-------------------------------------------------------------- 
\usepackage{times}
%--------------------------------------------------------------
% Theorem-Like-Environment
\usepackage{theorem}
{\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[chapter]
\newtheorem{theorem}{\rule{0ex}{5ex}Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[chapter]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{definition}{\rule{0ex}{5ex}Definition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter] }
%--------------------------------------------------------
\newenvironment{proof}{\begin{paragraph}
          {Proof}\vspace{-1cm}}{\end{paragraph}}
\newenvironment{solution}{\begin{paragraph}
          {Solution}\vspace{-1cm}}{\end{paragraph}}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: @Zarko I think you should not close this question in favor of another thread that did not solve the OP's problem. While I also am not able to reproduce the issue, there should be another way, which really helps the OP. So I reopened the question.

Comment: @Zarko While it seems that both of us cannot solve the OP's problem, someone else might. So I prefer to keep the question open such that the someone else has a chance to post an answer. I feel that the answer could be "update your TeX installation and try again" but I am not sure.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat thank you for your favor and suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you not believed me, that your codes works for me.

**How I tested your code:**

- Used was copy your MWE provided in question.
- In MWE instead of `\usepackage{UTMThesis}` was used its code, which you provide in your question.
- Test was performed by use of the MikTeX, updated  2020.02.18 on Windows 10 machine.

Complete test document :

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt,a4paper]{book}
%\usepackage{UTMThesis}%------------------------------------------------------------------
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% The package UTMthesis.sty will produce the output    %
% of a thesis according to UTM Thesis Manual,          %
% School of Graduate Studies, 2007.                    %
% Yusof Yaacob, Department of Mathematical Sciences,             %
% Faculty of Science,  Universiti Teknologi Malaysia   %
% 81310 Johor Bahru, Malaysia                          %
% e-mail: yusofby@utm.my                               %
% 24 December 2009                                     %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% LaTeX cod for chapter header
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{
  %\vspace*{20\p@}   %  \vspace*{15\p@}
  {\parindent \z@
      \centering
    \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter

      \normalsize
           \bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
       \par\nobreak
              \vskip 1.4\baselineskip
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \normalsize
         \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
       \vskip 1.4\baselineskip %
  }}
\def\@schapter#1{\if@twocolumn
                   \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{#1}]%
                 \else
                   \@makeschapterhead{#1}
                   \@afterheading
                 \fi}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{
  %\vspace*{20\p@} % \vspace*{20\p@} %
  {\parindent \z@
    \centering
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \normalsize
    \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
         \vskip 1.4\baselineskip
  }}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{CHAPTER}
%------------------------------------------------------------
% Commands for layout
   %\setlength{\topmargin}{-1.2cm}
   %\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1.7cm}   %\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1.46cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{14.5cm}
   \setlength{\textheight}{24.5cm} %  \setlength{\textheight}{24.5cm}
   %\setlength{\headheight}{2mm}
    %\setlength{\headsep}{10.175mm}
%-------------------------------------------------------------
% Command for 1.5 spacing
   %\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
%\usepackage{doublespace}
%\setstretch{1.5}
%-------------------------------------------------------------
% Command for  indentation
   \setlength\parindent{.5in}
   \usepackage{indentfirst} %1st line indented after section...
%-------------------------------------------------------------
% Command for space between paragraph
  \makeatletter
    %\setlength{\parskip}{1.5\baselineskip \@plus 3ex
                %  \@minus 2.0ex}
    \setlength{\parskip}{2\baselineskip \@plus .01ex
                  \@minus .01ex}
   \makeatother
%-------------------------------------------------------------
% Commands for no hyphenation and right justified
    \hyphenpenalty=10000 \sloppy
    \raggedbottom
%-------------------------------------------------------------
% Command to get rid of default running head
   \pagestyle{myheadings}
%-------------------------------------------------------------
% Command for  page number
%  \makeatletter
%    \renewcommand{\ps@plain}{%
%    \renewcommand{\@oddhead}{\hfill\textrm{\thepage}}
%    \renewcommand{\@evenhead}{\@oddhead}
%    \renewcommand{\@evenfoot}{}
%    \renewcommand{\@oddfoot}{}  }
%   \makeatother
%-----------------------------------------------------------------

 %For section font
 % \usepackage{sectsty}
 %  \chapterfont{\centering\normalsize\uppercase}
 %  \sectionfont{\normalsize\uppercase}
 % \subsectionfont{\normalsize}
 % \subsubsectionfont{\itshape\normalsize}
%---------------------------------------------------------
%--------------------------------------------------------------
% Commands for REFERENCES name
\renewcommand{\bibname}{REFERENCES}
%--------------------------------------------------------------
% Commands to change vertical space in section and subsection
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection
  {section}%      % the name
  {1}             % the level
  {0cm}           % the indent
  {1.0cm}         % the beforeskip
  {0.01cm}    %{0.5cm}    % the afterskip
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries} } % the style
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection
  {subsection}%   % the name
  {2}             % the leve2
  {0cm}           % the indent
  {1.0cm}         % the beforeskip
  {0.01cm} %{0.5cm}        % the afterskip
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries} } % the style
\makeatother
%--------------------------------------------------------------
% Commands to change horizontal space in section and subsection
% for times romans
   \renewcommand{\thesection} % space between sect. etc.
     {\thechapter.\arabic{section}\hspace{.12in}}
    \renewcommand{\thesubsection}
       {\thesection\hspace{-.3cm}.\arabic{subsection} \hspace{-.135cm}}
%--------------------------------------------------------------
% Commands for  TocLoFT
  \usepackage{tocloft}
    %\cftsetrmarg{2.75cm} %
     \cftsetrmarg{1.5cm} %
       \cftsetpnumwidth{1.25cm}
       %\cftsetpnumwidth{1.25cm}
    \renewcommand{\cftdot}{} % get rid of dots
%Table of Contents
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{}        % off tocname
\setlength{\cftchapindent}{.8cm}      % chapter indent
\setlength{\cftsecindent}{2.3cm}      % section indent
\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{3.25cm}  % subsection indent
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{1.45cm}  % chp number width
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%  \renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{\rule{1.75ex}{0ex}}
%   \renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{\rule{1.75ex}{0ex}}
%   \renewcommand{\cftsubsecafterpnum}{\rule{1.75ex}{0ex}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{\rule{0.75ex}{0ex}}
   \renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{\rule{0.75ex}{0ex}}
   \renewcommand{\cftsubsecafterpnum}{\rule{0.75ex}{0ex}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   \renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont}
%-------------------------------------------------------------
%List of Table
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{2.5cm}  %\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{2.5cm}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{} % off lotname
%\setlength{\cfttabindent}{-.015cm}      % table indent %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setlength{\cfttabindent}{-.1cm}      % table indent %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
             \renewcommand{\cfttabafterpnum}{\rule{2ex}{0ex}}
\cftsetrmarg{3cm}
%------------------------------------------------------------
 %List of Figure
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{2.5cm}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{} % off lofname
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{-.1cm}      % figure indent %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   \renewcommand{\cftfigafterpnum}{\rule{2ex}{0ex}}
%-------------------------------------------------------------
%-------------------------------------------------------------
% Command for bold caption
\makeatletter
  \long\def\@makecaption#1#2{\vskip 10\p@   % caption parameter
       \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{{#1\,\,\,\,\,} #2} %%%%%
       \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize         % caption parameter
           {#1\,\,\,\,\,}  #2\par  % caption parameter
       \else                                   % caption parameter
           \hbox to\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}  % caption parameter
   \fi}                                            % caption parameter
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{table}}

%--------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{paralist} %refine list item
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{latexsym,amsmath,amssymb} % math symbols
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{graphicx} % .eps graphic
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{lscape} % for landscape
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{times}
%--------------------------------------------------------------
% Theorem-Like-Environment
\usepackage{theorem}
{\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[chapter]
\newtheorem{theorem}{\rule{0ex}{5ex}Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[chapter]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{definition}{\rule{0ex}{5ex}Definition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter] }
%--------------------------------------------------------
\newenvironment{proof}{\begin{paragraph}
          {Proof}\vspace{-1cm}}{\end{paragraph}}
\newenvironment{solution}{\begin{paragraph}
          {Solution}\vspace{-1cm}}{\end{paragraph}}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% end of UTMThesis

\usepackage{cite} % change  cite from [1,2,3] to [1-3] etc for number system
\makeatletter                        % change from
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{#1.}  % [1] to 1. etc
\makeatother                         %  in list of references
%----------------------------------------------------------------
\setlength{\voffset}{-2.11cm}
\setlength{\hoffset}{-.4cm}
%---------------------------------------------------------
\setlength{\textwidth}{14.5cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{24.5cm}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
%\pagestyle{plain}
%-------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{\vspace{-.35cm}\thepage}  %
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%----------------own-----------
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,tikzmark}
%-------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}
\begingroup\larger[4]
\[
\tikzmarknode{n1}{\rho\frac{D\vec V}{Dt}}~=~\tikzmarknode{n2}{-\nabla p}
+ \tikzmarknode{n3}{\rho\vec g}+\tikzmarknode{n4}{\mu\nabla^2\vec V}\]
\endgroup
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,shorten <=1mm,font=\footnotesize\sffamily]
\begin{scope}[nodes={text width=6.5em,align=left},node distance=1ex]
\node (e1) {\underline{Total derivative}};
\node[right=of e1.north east,anchor=north west] (e2) {\underline{Pressure gradient}\\[1em]
    Fluid flows in the direction\dots};
\node[right=of e2.north east,anchor=north west] (e3) {\underline{Body force term}\\[1em]
    External forces\dots};
\node[right=of e3.north east,anchor=north west] (e4) {\underline{Diffusion term}\\[1em]
    For a Newtonian fluid it is equatl to \dots};
\end{scope}
\node[below=0.5ex of e1.south] (eq){$=$};
\node[below=0.5ex of eq] (tot) {$\rho\left[\frac{\partial \vec V}{\partial t}
    +\left(\vec V\cdot\vec\nabla\right)\vec V\right]$};
\path (tot.south west) -- (tot.south east) coordinate[pos=0.25] (tot1)
coordinate[pos=0.75] (tot2);
\node[below left=2ex and 0ex of tot.south,text width=4em,align=left] (c1)
{Change of velosity};
\node[below right=2ex and 0ex of tot.south,text width=4em,align=left] (c2) {Convective term};
\draw[cyan,-stealth] (c1) -- (tot1);
\draw[cyan,-stealth] (c2) -- (tot2);
\begin{scope}[overlay]
\foreach \X in {1,...,4}
{\draw[cyan,-stealth] (e\X) -- (n\X);}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c c c}
        \hline
        a&b&c\\
        d&e&f\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I compile it twice and got the following result:

[image]

without any warnings, nor errors, nor crash.

**How can you confirm my result:**

- Copy above document to your editor and save it with some name.
- Compile it twice.
- if you not receive the same result as me, than you have some mess in your LaTeX installation. Check it again! In the case, that you have MikTeX too, and it is installed in administrative and user format, you need to upgrade both (see [maintain-and-update-a-miktex-installation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108447/how-should-one-maintain-and-update-a-miktex-installation)).
- If you compilation of my document works, but with your document still have the same problem as you reported, than your document hide something what is not enclosed in your document presented in question.

**What you can do:**

- write new, simple MWE, something like this:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\[
\tikzmarknode{n1}{\rho\frac{D\vec V}{Dt}}~=~\tikzmarknode{n2}{-\nabla p}
+ \tikzmarknode{n3}{\rho\vec g}+\tikzmarknode{n4}{\mu\nabla^2\vec V}
\]

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,shorten <=1mm,font=\footnotesize\sffamily]
\begin{scope}[nodes={text width=6.5em,align=left},node distance=1ex]
\node (e1) {\underline{Total derivative}};
\node[right=of e1.north east,anchor=north west] (e2) {\underline{Pressure gradient}\\[1em]
    Fluid flows in the direction\dots};
\node[right=of e2.north east,anchor=north west] (e3) {\underline{Body force term}\\[1em]
    External forces\dots};
\node[right=of e3.north east,anchor=north west] (e4) {\underline{Diffusion term}\\[1em]
    For a Newtonian fluid it is equatl to \dots};
\end{scope}
\node[below=0.5ex of e1.south] (eq){$=$};
\node[below=0.5ex of eq] (tot) {$\rho\left[\frac{\partial \vec V}{\partial t}
    +\left(\vec V\cdot\vec\nabla\right)\vec V\right]$};
\path (tot.south west) -- (tot.south east) coordinate[pos=0.25] (tot1)
coordinate[pos=0.75] (tot2);
\node[below left=2ex and 0ex of tot.south,text width=4em,align=left] (c1)
{Change of velosity};
\node[below right=2ex and 0ex of tot.south,text width=4em,align=left] (c2) {Convective term};
\draw[cyan,-stealth] (c1) -- (tot1);
\draw[cyan,-stealth] (c2) -- (tot2);
\begin{scope}[overlay]
\foreach \X in {1,...,4}
{\draw[cyan,-stealth] (e\X) -- (n\X);}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c c c}
        \hline
        a&b&c\\
        d&e&f\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

- Test if it works. It works for me and it should give the similar result as is shown above (it will differ only in equation's font size).
- If test fail, then you have problems with your LaTeX installation.
- If test works, add `UTMThesis`.

  - If it still work, continue with adding in step-by-step manner other package and see, if this test document still works.
  - If not, check the content of this package (if it the same as you show in your question) and if in your PC exist only one version of this package
- Continue this procedure with adding small chunks of your document code.

**Conclusion**
Codes provided by you in the question works. It not contain cause of your problem. The cause is hiden somewhere else in your document or in your LaTeX installation.

Comment: Now it is working when by using the code instead of `\usepackage{UTMThesis}` as you suggested. thank you so much for your kind assistance.

Comment: The error is here:  In `UTMThesis.sty`  in line `61-62`, `%\usepackage{doublespace}` `%\setstretch{1.5}`. we suppose to use these, may be during editing I comment these lines in MWE by mistake.

Comment: I'm glad to hear, that you resolve your problem. BTW, someone should clean-up and modernized this package. For example with use of the `geometry` package , `times` is obsolete˙etc. Also move of the obligated package for document style to begin of the package is very sensible :-)